# I'm trying to reverse an array line by line

Tags: java, arrays

To clarify, this IS a homework assignment. I'm merely looking for advice, I'm not looking for someone to do my homework for me.

I've already done the first half. It uses two arrays to print an Asterisk design (in this case, the letter 'S'. That works fine. Then, I skip two lines and print the design but flipped (so each line is reversed). It seems to be working fine, but when I run the program, it prints two S's and the second one isn't reversed. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Design {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
       char [] array = new char [150];
       for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index ++) 
       {
         array [index] = '#';
       }
       int [] indexNumbers = {
           0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,
           60,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,89,99,109,119,129,139,140,
           141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149
       };
       for (int i = 0; i < indexNumbers.length; i++) 
       {
         array [indexNumbers[i]] = ' ';
       }
      for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index ++)
      {
         if (index % 10 == 0 && index > 0) 
         System.out.println();
         System.out.print (array[index]);
      }

      //Now, to reverse the letter

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();

      int lines = 5;
      for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
        if (i >= lines)
          lines += 10;
        char temp = array [i];
        array [i] = array [lines - i - 1];
        array [lines - i - 1] = temp;
      }
      for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index ++)
      {
        if (index % 10 == 0 && index > 0) 
          System.out.println();
          System.out.print (array[index]);
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT: Yeah... the design is in spaces, everything else is asterisks.

Comment: Having rapidly skimmer the code, I would say that you need a loop for(int i=charArray.lenght-1; i>=0; i--) and you're set

Comment: Asterisk design? I see only '#' and spaces, where the S is draw by the spaces, not the '#'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your reversing is a bit confused.... makes it easier if you do it in two loops.

```
for (int row = 0; row < (array.Length / 10); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
        int rowStart = row * 10;
        int rowEnd = rowStart + 9;
        char temp = array[rowStart + col];                    
        array[rowStart + col] = array[rowEnd - col];
        array[rowEnd - col] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Using nested loops didn't even cross my mind, but it works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First, why don't you use `String[]` or `char[][]`? Instead you are using a simple array to put multiple lines within. This makes your code confuse and brittle.

To swap an array, the rule is generally simple: Get the first and the last line and swap them. Get the second and the second last, and swap them, get the third and the third last and swap them... Until you get to the middle. This will be much easier if you have an array where each element is a line (like in an `String[]` or in an `char[][]`).

If you need to keep the idea of a simple `char[]` where each 10-char block is a line, simply swap each 10-char block like I stated above.

If you don't want to change the general behaviour of your program, this is the problematic block:

```
  int lines = 5;
  for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
     if (i >= lines)
        lines += 10;
    char temp = array [i];
    array [i] = array [lines - i - 1];
    array [lines - i - 1] = temp;
  }
```

You are not swapping lines here, instead you are swapping chars. This way, your if is not checking and skipping lines, but is instead checking and skipping chars.

This is better:

```
  int lines = array.length / 10;
  for (int i = 0; i<= lines / 2; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          char t = array[i * 10 + j];
          array[i * 10 + j] = array[(lines - i - 1) * 10 + j];
          array[(lines - i - 1) * 10 + j] = t;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So..

First of all, start by printing `'#'` instead of `' '`, and `'.'` instead of `'#'`. You will see more clearly what's going on.

Second, you have a problem in the reverse, you are actually not reversing anything, the way you calculate the index `lines - i - 1` is wrong. The good way is `(i / 10) * 10 + (10 - (i % 10)) -1`. Yep, is kinda horrible, but if you want that in one line, using a one-dimension array, there it is. Now it's up to you to understand it, and integrate it in your code ;)